# cannot reach my inner breakpoint

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I'm running the following code:

```
 hashedUrlDataList.Select(mDalHashedUrlData.Save);
```

I have put a breakpoint  in the called delegate,

```
public HashedUrlData Save(HashedUrlData item)
    {
//breakpoint here 
           }
```

but it doesn't stop there.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Enumerable.Select is Lazy.
Try this and tell me if your break point is caught

```
hashedUrlDataList.Select(mDalHashedUrlData.Save).ToList();
```

Or the basic:

```
hashedUrlDataList.Select(mDalHashedUrlData.Save).GetEnumerator().MoveNext()
```

It just works if you have at least one element.

You can do it too:

```
    hashedUrlDataList.Select(mDalHashedUrlData.Save).Any();
```

Any() do the same that GetEnumerator().MoveNext()

I think that what you want is:

```
List<HashedUrlData> hashedUrlDataList = new List<HashedUrlData>();
hashedUrlDataList.ForEach(Save);
```

Comment: how do I force invocation without ToList() ?

Comment: You want force without ToList or without any kind of enumeration? You need to enumerate it, no matter how. How the method Save could be called if it doesn´t have a HashedUrlData?
The most basic call is hashedUrlDataList.Select(mDalHashedUrlData.Save).GetEnumerator().MoveNext();

Answer (score 5):

Your method will be called when you'll enumerate the result of `Select()` not when declared.

Comment: So how do I force invocation without ToList() ?

Comment: Enumerate it! Your code is just a _definition_ of the expression you want to execute but actually it'll be executed only when needed. If, for example, you enumerate the result of the Select() then you function will be called for each element. If you call ToList() you force to create a list with all elements. You can do it but you probably you don't need it.

Comment: foreach (var item in hashedUrlDataList.Select(mDalHashedUrlData.Save)) item.ToString();

Answer (score 0):

LINQ is for querying data; it's not intended to cause side-effects.

If you're more interested in the side efects of your `Save`method than the `HashedUrlData` instance it returns, you should really be calling

```
foreach (HashedUrlData h in hashedUrlDataList)
{
    h.Save();
}
```

If you will eventually be using the returned values and this is just an intermediate/debugging stage, then by all means use LINQ. Just be aware that Save will only be called as you access each returned value, or call something else that enumerates the whole enumerator as the other answers have shown.